# Finding the divisables of an integer in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hello all i am just starting to code and I am trying to solve the following question:
The function below should accept two arguments, an integer and a list with integers

The function should return a list with True and False for all integers in the list
by which the first argument is divisable and False otherwise.

For example, the function call:

```
main(10, [12, 2, 22, 5 ])
```

should `return [False, True, False, True]`

this is my code:

```
def main(integer_1, list_1):
    result= “
    for element in list_1:
        if integer_1%element==0:
            result += "True"
        else:
            result += "False"

print(main(10, [12, 2, 22, 5 ]))
```

However it returns `None`

Answer (score 1):

You must return your result and it would be better to use list instead of string for it.
Init it with:

```
your_list = []
```

and then call:

```
your_list.append(new_element)
```

Where new_element is  True of False in this case
And at the end:

```
return your_list
```

Answer (score 0):

you should `return` your result at the end of the function like this:

```
def main(integer_1, list_1):
    result = ''
    for element in list_1:
        if integer_1 % element == 0:
            result += "True"
        else:
            result += "False"
    return result
```

which will give you this out put if you execute the rest of your code:

`FalseTrueFalseTrue`

so you might want to add a single space to the end of string representations of "True" and "False" which will give you this output at the end:

`False True False True`